# How to read every line from a txt file and print starting from the line which starts with "Created_Date" in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

```
5G_Fixed_Wireless_Dashboard_TestScedule||||||||||||||||^M

Report Run Date||08/07/2018|||||||||||||||||||||^M

Requesting User Company||NEW|||||||||||||||||||||^M

Report Criteria|||||||||||||||||||||||^M

" Service Job Updated from Date:

  Service Job Updated to Date:

  Service Job Created from Date: 08/06/2018

   Service Job Created to Date:

 Service Job Status:

Resolution Code:"|||||||||||||||||||||||^M

Created Date|Job Status|Schedule Date|Job 
    Number|Service Job Type|Verizon Customer Order 
    Number|Verizon Location Code|Service|Installation 
    Duration|Part Number
```

I want to print starting from Created Date. The result 
   file should be something like below.

```
   Created Date|Job Status|Schedule Date|Job 
   Number|Service Job Type|Verizon Customer Order 
   Number|Verizon Location Code|Service|Installation 
   Duration|Part Number
```

I have tried the following lines after you people linked me to some other questions. But my requirement is to print the result to the same file.

FILELIST=`find $MFROUTDIR -maxdepth 1 -name "XXXXXX_5G_Order_*.txt"`

for nextFile in $FILELIST;do

```
    cat $nextFile | sed -n -e '/Created Date/,$p'
```

done

By writing above lines of code, output is printed on console. Could you please suggest some way to print it in same file.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This can be done in multiple ways e.g. bash, sed, awk etc

Comment: @NavyaNaiduChamidisetty: Not in comments, add this code by editing your question.

Comment: First, you really don't want to write back to the same file.  However, since you will choose to ignore that advice, you have many options.  Possibly you will be content to simply add `-i` to your sed invocation.

Comment: @WilliamPursell When I add -i to sed command, it is saying "sed: no input files". I used                                                                               
 cat $nextFile | sed -i -n -e '/Created Date/,$p'

Comment: @WilliamPursell It worked when I added                                               
  cat $nextFile | sed -i -n -e '/Created Date/,$p' $nextFile.  Thanks for your response

Comment: @WilliamPursell I have a small issue here like when a newfile is created with data it is appending ^M character after each row. Could you please help me resolving this. Actually I added this line "sed -i -e 's/\^M//g' $nextFile" after cat statement as mentioned in above comment. But it did not work. I am still seeing ^M

Comment: The ^M is most easily resolved with `dos2unix`

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with a simple `awk` command:

```
awk '/^Created Date/{p=1} p' file
```

```
Created Date|Job Status|Schedule Date|Job
    Number|Service Job Type|Verizon Customer Order
    Number|Verizon Location Code|Service|Installation
    Duration|Part Number
```

We set a flag `p` to `1` when we encounter a line that starts with `Created Date`. Later we use awk default action to print each line when `p==1`.

---

**References:**

- [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)
- [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: Could you please explain what does '{p=1}p'  do in above command. I am completely new to shell scripting

Comment: I did not use awk, I used "cat $nextFile | sed -i -n -e '/Created Date/,$p' $nextFile"  and it worked.

Comment: I have a small issue here like when a newfile is created with data it is appending ^M character after each row. Could you please help me resolving this. Actually I added this line "sed -i -e 's/\^M//g' $nextFile" after cat statement as mentioned in above comment. But it did not work. I am still seeing ^M

Comment: Since you're not using my suggested awk` solution I am unable to advise.